# Allow inbound and outbound calls on same asterisk (number not registered)

Tags: centos, asterisk

I have a particular case where carrier (not provider), give me calls without having to register. On carrier side, numbers have an associated IP which is used to route any call. 
FOr outgoing call, I just need to push call to carrier server (without registration).
For sending outgoing call, I have a Cisco SPA504G, willing to buy several more if I can find a working solution.

After testing a lot of configurations, I am able to do outbound calls or inbound calls with changing settings but I am unable to have both working at the same time.
From what I saw, the "outcall" in sip.conf is used on inbound calls which I don't want. I tried a lot of configurations with online tips/howto but my case seems a little particular.

Please find below my configuration and please help me resolve this problem :)

**sip.conf**

```
[general]
maxexpirey=3600
defaultexpirey=3600
registertimeout=300
context=default
transport=udp
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
dtmfmode=auto
allowguest=yes
language=ja


[151]
type=user
;nat=force_rport,comedia
secret=151secret
host=dynamic
regext=151
context=fxsgroup
;directmedia=nonat
;directrtpsetup=no
allowguest=yes
defaultuser=151
fromuser=151
;nat=route
[outcall]
defaultuser=03XXXX9510
type=peer
;secret=03XXXX9510
host=10.254.32.1
fromuser=0367449510
context=fxsgroup
;trustrpid = yes
;sendrpid = yes
;canreinvite = no
;directmedia=no
allowguest=no
```

extensions.conf

```
[default]
;[03XXXX9510] ALEX 03XXXX9510 (
    exten => 03XXXX9510,Dial(SIP/151@outcall,60)
;   exten => 03XXXX9510,n,Dial(SIP/03XXXX2740@outcall,80)
    exten => 03XXXX9510,n,Hangup

[fxsgroup]
;151 ext
exten => 151,1,Dial(SIP/151,60,rT)

exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX, 1,Set(CALLERID(num)=03XXXX9510)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX, n, Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@outcall, 20)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX, n, Congestion()
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXX, n, Hangup()

exten => _XXXXXXXXXX, 1,Set(CALLERID(num)=03XXXX9510)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX, n, Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@outcall, 20)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX, n, Congestion()
exten => _XXXXXXXXXX, n, Hangup()
```

trace in sip debug (inbound call going to outcall and not to default context)

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:10.254.32.1:5060 --->
INVITE sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: afb491a0d719ece155373ec8ea0a4578@10.254.32.1
CSeq: 1 INVITE
From: <sip:080XXXX2374@172.30.20.4>;tag=12d7dc8113006c-f5c541eb42415
To: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.254.32.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bKfbd30971b55b4da33c7b37b23d0d2bf5
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:080XXXX2374@10.254.32.1:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE
Supported: timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 138

v=0
o=- 1494691107189 0 IN IP4 10.254.32.1
s=-
c=IN IP4 10.254.32.1
t=0 0
m=audio 57396 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=sendrecv
<------------->
--- (12 headers 8 lines) ---
Sending to 10.254.32.1:5060 (no NAT)
Sending to 10.254.32.1:5060 (no NAT)
Using INVITE request as basis request - afb491a0d719ece155373ec8ea0a4578@10.254.32.1
Found peer 'outcall' for '080XXXX2374' from 10.254.32.1:5060
Found RTP audio format 0
Found audio description format PCMU for ID 0
Capabilities: us - (ulaw), peer - audio=(ulaw)/video=(nothing)/text=(nothing), combined - (ulaw)
Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event|), peer - 0x0 (nothing), combined - 0x0 (nothing)
Peer audio RTP is at port 10.254.32.1:57396
Looking for 03XXXX9510 in fxsgroup (domain 172.30.20.4)
sip_route_dump: route/path hop: <sip:080XXXX2374@10.254.32.1:5060>

<--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 10.254.32.1:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.254.32.1:5060;branch=z9hG4bKfbd30971b55b4da33c7b37b23d0d2bf5;received=10.254.32.1
From: <sip:080XXXX2374@172.30.20.4>;tag=12d7dc8113006c-f5c541eb42415
To: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4>
Call-ID: afb491a0d719ece155373ec8ea0a4578@10.254.32.1
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 14.2.1
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uas
Contact: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4:5060>
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
Audio is at 12388
Adding codec ulaw to SDP
Adding non-codec 0x1 (telephone-event) to SDP
Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 10.254.32.1:5060:
INVITE sip:151@10.254.32.1 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.30.20.4:5060;branch=z9hG4bK60e97466
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4>;tag=as53476181
To: <sip:151@10.254.32.1>
Contact: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4:5060>
Call-ID: 2d64de691eeee2bf33cd4fce0c440ba9@172.30.20.4:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 14.2.1
Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:58:27 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 249

v=0
o=root 1244963103 1244963103 IN IP4 172.30.20.4
s=Asterisk PBX 14.2.1
c=IN IP4 172.30.20.4
t=0 0
m=audio 12388 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv

---

<--- SIP read from UDP:10.254.32.1:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 486 Busy Here
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.30.20.4:5060;branch=z9hG4bK60e97466
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4>;tag=as53476181
To: <sip:151@10.254.32.1>
Call-ID: 2d64de691eeee2bf33cd4fce0c440ba9@172.30.20.4:5060
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Contact: <sip:151@10.254.32.1:5060>
Allow: OPTIONS, INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (10 headers 0 lines) ---
Transmitting (no NAT) to 10.254.32.1:5060:
ACK sip:151@10.254.32.1 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.30.20.4:5060;branch=z9hG4bK60e97466
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4>;tag=as53476181
To: <sip:151@10.254.32.1>
Contact: <sip:03XXXX9510@172.30.20.4:5060>
Call-ID: 2d64de691eeee2bf33cd4fce0c440ba9@172.30.20.4:5060
CSeq: 102 ACK
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 14.2.1
Content-Length: 0
```

I am sure there is a solution, probably just a step ahead ;)

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your SIP user 'outcall' to 'trunk a' because that's what is it; yes, both inbound and outbound calls are going to use that.

Asterisk is doing exactly what you told it to do.  Calls that hit the endpoint at 10.254.32.1 belong to the SIP user 'outcalls' whose default context is fxsgroup.  Unfortunately the user 03XXXX9510 does not exist in the fxsgroup context, so your call is failing.